# InAppSettingsKit bar with done button disappears

Tags: inappsettingskit

I've integrated InAppSettingsKit in my app and it works great 90% of the time.

However, 10% of the time when I'm in the modal view, the top bar with the done button just disappears, leaving the user no option to close the settings.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Sounds strange, never saw this and never heard of it from any IASK user.

Comment: I don't know if this helps or not -- but when it disappears, there is just white space.  If I put the app in the background and then come back into the app, the rest of the settings shift up, and the whitespace is gone.  Since the user can't exit the settings, the only option is to kill the app and restart.

Comment: Lastly, here is my settings instantiation:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29836403/ECS-Apps/InAppSettings.rtf

Comment: The instantiation is pretty much from the sample app. (Note you don't need to implement all delegate methods, esp. below line 27, if you don't make use of advanced features.) Can you reproduce the problem in the sample app? If not, I suggest looking in your code. I suspect you've a bug in your viewDidUnload, didReceiveMemoryWarning or willEnterBackground code.

Comment: Based on the sample apps, I had added in didReceiveMemoryWarning: "self.appSettingsViewController = nil;"  and in dealloc:"[appSettingsViewController release]; appSettingsViewController = nil;"

Should I remove those?

Comment: If helpful, this is the precise code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29836403/ECS-Apps/More.rtf

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I determined today that this only occurs if I rotate the device to landscape and then to portrait.  So, the problem seems to occur there.

Comment: Problem Solved!!  The issue was with how my app supported auto rotation (which it was NOT intended to support.)  It turns out that I was still using "[window addsubview..." for the root view controller, instead of the new "window.rootViewController =".  Once I changed that one line, my problem disappeared!

Comment: Post it as an answer and mark it as correct!